# tSQLt.run does nothing in one Query window but works in another

Tags: tsqlt

I have created 3 test classes.

I can, from one query window run the following for all test classes.

```
tSQLt.Run 'class1';
tSQLt.Run 'class2';
tSQLt.run 'class3';
```

But from all other query window, the calls above simply don't work.

So, to make sure I have a clean window, I put the focus on the query window where the calls work ... I hit CTRL+N to get a new windows, same user, same database, and I type `tSQLt.Run 'class1'`, hit F5 and the little green spinner with "executing query" is visible at the bottom and it looks like it will keep spinning for a long long time.

Anyone available to help out on this.

Regards,
Bertin

Comment: it's very likely that you have open transaction running on the first window. If you close the window#1 while #2 is running, would it warn you about open transaction?  Will the #2 transaction finish when you closed the first window?

Comment: Perhaps ... in another window, I checked sys.dm_exec_requests and couldn't see anything running (although if the process was waiting for a command, perhaps I would not have seen anything).

Comment: Finally, after closing everything and restarting SSMS, everything is now working properly.  Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if you delete this question. It doesn't have much value and housekeeping is just a good thing

Answer (score 0):

There probably was a running transaction. I closed everything and re-opened SSMS ... things are back to "normal".

Thanks,
Bertin